# Rust importing .rs fails

Tags: import, rust

I have three files in my `src/` folder: `main.rs`, `lib.rs` and `cfgtools.rs`. I want to import `cfgtools.rs`.

**main.rs**

```
extern crate cfgtools;

use cfgtools::*;

fn main() {
    let os = get_os();
    println!("Your OS: {}",os);
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
pub mod cfgtools;
```

**cfgtools.rs**

```
pub fn get_os() -> &'static str {
        let mut sys:&'static str = "unknown";
        if cfg!(target_os = "windows")   { sys = "windows" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "macos")     { sys = "macos" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "ios")       { sys = "ios" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "linux")     { sys = "linux" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "android")   { sys = "android" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "freebsd")   { sys = "freebsd" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "dragonfly") { sys = "dragonfly" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "bitrig")    { sys = "bitrig" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "openbsd")   { sys = "openbsd" };
        if cfg!(target_os = "netbsd")    { sys = "netbsd" };
        return sys;
}
```

Still, I get an error:

```
   Compiling sys_recog v0.1.0 (file:///home/sessho/rust/sys_recog)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `cfgtools`
  --> main.rs:17:1
   |
17 | extern crate cfgtools;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

I am new to Rust and this concept of importing.

Comment: How do you compile? What command do you execute in your terminal?

Comment: It's simply `cargo build`.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your `Cargo.toml` then? :)  (PS: StackOverflow pro tip: if you want to notify someone, better write @UserName in your comment!)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt doesn't matter, already solved

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is some confusion between crates and modules.  All of your source files are modules in the same crate.  It sounds like `lib.rs` isn't needed, and you just want a `cfgtools` module.  `extern crate` is used to import other libraries kept separately; extern crates also need to be declared in `Cargo.toml` so that Cargo can find them.

So it should be something like this:

`main.rs`:

```
// Declare the module, which will be there as cfgtools.rs in the same directory.
mod cfgtools;

// Make things in cfgtools visible.  Note that wildcard imports
// aren't recommended as they can make it confusing to find where
// things actually come from.
use cfgtools::foo;

// and use it:
fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

And `cfgtools.rs`:

```
// Note pub to make it visible outside the module
pub fn foo() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I put those files in `src/` after `cargo init --bin .` to create a new blank crates, and `cargo run` prints out the message.